# codeigniter model query where date('') postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

i have a codeigniter web with mvc, and i will got the data from table 'rain_density' with (date) data type value where the month is feb(2) or jan(1)

So how to got the data with month, i have tried on model with the $this->query("select * from rainfall_density where extract(MONTH FROM waktu)=$month")
but it also wrong.

```
    function get_curahhujan_bymonth($month) {
        $query = $this->db->query("select * from curah_hujan where extract(MONTH FROM waktu)=$month");

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    }
```

So any idea of this problem ??

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT - there is a sample with month. Your query looks OK. Try to remove `where`, instead put `limit 100` to have results limited anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`MONTH()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-month-function.php)

```
function get_curahhujan_bymonth($month) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM curah_hujan WHERE MONTH(waktu) = '$month' ");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    if (!empty($result)) {
        return $result;
    }
}
```